# Selenium click on String array of elements

Tags: java, arrays, string, selenium, click

I have an String array that I get from a text file or CSV. I want Selenium to take that array and click on each checkbox element. The elements have this naming convention:

```
1.0.50.gecb16, 
1.1.50.gecb16, 
1.2.50.gecb16,
1.3.50.gecb16, ->to 50
```

I only want to click on the checkbox for each element to lets say 24

on this line:

> driver.findElement(By.name(i)).click();

**I am getting an error of:** The method name(String) in the type By is not applicable for the arguments (String[])

**Here is my Code:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("4off.txt"));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(inFile1.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(inFile1.nextLine());
    }

    String[] yourArray = sb.toString().split(", ");
    int i;

    System.out.println("This is the Array: " + "\n");
    Arrays.stream(yourArray).forEach(System.out::println);

    // launch Chrome and go to baseUrl
    driver.get(baseUrl);//baseUrl


   driver.findElement(By.name("pwd")).sendKeys(pass);

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("login_button")).click();
    System.out.println("ATTEMPTING Login CLICK");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'tabs\']/td[4]/a/img")).click();
    Thread.sleep(6000);
    System.out.println("ATTEMPTING Checkbox CLICK");


    ////This switches to the iframe called "mainContent"//// 
    driver.switchTo().frame("maincontent");

    ////For loop that will go through all of the elements in the array:
    for (i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.name(i)).click();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try yourArray[i] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simply means, that the method name doesn't accept an array as parameter.
Also, are you aware, that you're searching for numbers and not the actual names (eg. 1.3.50.gecb16) in your for loop?

Try something like this

```
 for (i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.name(yourArray[i])).click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= yourArray.length - 1; i++) {
        driver.findElement(By.name(yourArray[i])).clik();
    }
```